# Devices with poor wifi connection suck all the router's time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I tried to make the title the most explanatory as possible, I hope I did it.

There are some areas of the house with poor connectivity. 
When someones starts using a wifi connected device there, other people all over the house start having a slow connection.

For example, if anyone starts using internet in one of those poor connection rooms (they are farther away from the router), even someone who is in the living room, right next to the router gets crummy access. My guess is that the router gets too busy dealing with the poorer connectivity device, and then all the others are affected.

The router in question is a Hitron CVE-30360, provided by my ISP, is is, which is NOS (a portuguese ISP). (CVE30360_V2_ZON_SIP, versio 4.11.3.7.62.3.111)

I tried to manually set the channel (it had been on the Auto setting), didn't work. Then I tried to change the standards: changed b/g/n setting, to g/n, to no avail. 
Also looked for some QoS features, but found nothing...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The WAP needs to set its speed to that of the slowest client.

Comment: @RonMaupin What??? Why would it need that? With WAP you mean Wireless Aplication Protocol, right? Is there any alternative to this protocol? What can I do?

Comment: A WAP is a wireless access point. That is to what you connect with a Wi-Fi computer. It has been that way from the beginning. For instance, the original 802.11b had a maximum of 11 Mbps on 2.4 GHz. Later, 802.11g had a maximum of 45 Mbps on 2.4 GHz, but if there were _any_ devices that could only do 802.11b, then the WAP operated at 11 Mbps. You really need to learn more about Wi-Fi (IEEE 802.11).

Comment: @RonMaupin YOU need to learn more about 802.11. You are spreading a pervasive myth that has never been true. Having an client of an older/slower generation of 802.11 technology join a later AP does NOT knock the whole BSS down to the older/slower technology. Just like connecting a 10BASE-T device to a 10/100/1000 switch does NOT drop the whole switch down to 10BASE-T. The Wi-Fi Alliance's certification testing even has specific tests to ensure that no AP ("wireless router") can qualify for the "Wi-Fi" logo/branding if it drops the whole network down to old rates when an old client joins.

Comment: @Spiff, Wireless is not wired. Saying one doesn't do X is not a valid reason why the other doesn't. I don't have evidence to counter what you say, but it wasn't more than 2 years ago I was talking with people I'd expect to know this and they said more or less the same thing Ron did. Many routers use multiple radios to group devices of various capabilities and prevent the truly old ones from causing trouble for the newer ones.

Comment: @Kelthar, does it matter WHICH device(s) connect from the poorly served areas of the house? Do some cause less trouble than others when they get a weak signal?

Comment: @music2myear The presence of, say, a B STA can force, say, N STAs to use protection to keep the B STA from accidentally trampling on the N STAs' transmissions that the B STA can't see. This protection can slow down the N STAs a few percent, but it doesn't knock the whole BSS down to B-only mode. B STAs also use more airtime to transfer the same amount of data, so that sucks too. But adding a B client to an N AP does not make the N AP suddenly only use B PHY rates when talking to N clients. The N STAs and N AP still speak N PHY rates. Look at any 802.11 monitor-mode packet trace and you'll see.

Comment: @music2myear No, it doesn't matter which device is in the poorly served areas, the effect is the same.

Comment: Because B uses airtime less efficiently, the presence of a B-connected device will leave less airtime for G traffic. The entire network will not be dropping to actual B, but it will not be running at full G capability either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your Hitron router supports Airtime Fairness:  https://routerguide.net/airtime-fairness-on-or-off/

WiFi Access Points usually assign an equal number of frames to clients, but with Airtime Fairness, an equal amount of time is assigned for each client.  For more info:  https://support.ruckuswireless.com/answers/000002008

If it does not, or if it doesn't solve your problem, you could look into disabling WiFi on your Hitron router, getting another Access Point which supports Airtime Fairness, configure it in bridge mode and connect it to one of your Hitron's Ethernet ports.

Another option, which would still require another Access Point, is to configure WDS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system) or Repeating (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater).

-Rich Alloway (RogueWave)

PS - IIRC, 802.11g devices that are in a mixed environment with 802.11b devices must use 802.11b modulation and data rates for MAC management, but the payload may be encoded with higher modulation schemes and data rates.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Hitron CVE-30360 is buggy and never passed Wi-Fi certification (it's not in the certified products registry on the Wi-Fi Alliance's Wi-Fi.org website). Wi-Fi APs should never let a single slow client take up more than its share of the airtime, so a single slow client shouldn't be able to slow everyone down.

Try using a higher-quality AP.

Answer (score 0):

This happens most likely due to wifi collisions. You need to enable RTS/CTS on your router to avoid those collisions and get a stable connection without break downs.
More about it here: https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topics/network-security-101/rts-threshold-configuration-improved-wireless-network-performance/